# MySQL/MariaDB setting values with INTO inside cursor has incorrect iterations

Tags: mysql, sql, cursor, mariadb, select-into

Could someone please explain me why if I run this code:

```
    BEGIN
        -- Declare loop constructs --
        DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE; 

        -- Declare Person variables --
        DECLARE s_trnsf_id INT(11) DEFAULT NULL;
    DECLARE s_trnsf_trnsp_id INT(11) DEFAULT NULL;
    DECLARE s_trnsf_bacc_id INT(11) DEFAULT NULL;
    DECLARE s_trnsf_cus_id INT(11) DEFAULT NULL;
    DECLARE s_trnsf_bacc_amnt DECIMAL(18,4) DEFAULT NULL;
    DECLARE s_trnsf_recidue_amnt DECIMAL(18,4) DEFAULT NULL;

    DECLARE t_trnsf_id INT(11) DEFAULT NULL;
    DECLARE t_trnsf_recidue_amnt DECIMAL(18,4) DEFAULT NULL;

    DECLARE c1 INT(11) DEFAULT 0;

        -- Declare Cursor --
        DECLARE member_cursor CURSOR FOR 
            SELECT trnsf_id, trnsf_trnsp_id, trnsf_bacc_id, trnsf_cus_id, trnsf_bacc_amnt,trnsf_recidue_amnt
    FROM d_transfers
    WHERE 
    trnsf_bacc_amnt < 0
    AND trnsf_recidue_amnt <> 0
    ORDER BY #trnsf_trnsp_id ASC, trnsf_bacc_id ASC, trnsf_cus_id ASC, 
    trnsf_transfer_ts ASC;

        -- Declare Continue Handler --
        DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

        OPEN member_cursor;

        read_loop: LOOP

    SET c1 = c1+1;

            -- Fetch data from cursor --
            FETCH member_cursor 
            INTO s_trnsf_id,
    s_trnsf_trnsp_id,
    s_trnsf_bacc_id,
    s_trnsf_cus_id,
    s_trnsf_bacc_amnt,
    s_trnsf_recidue_amnt;

            -- Exit loop if finished --
            IF done THEN
                LEAVE read_loop;
            END IF;

    ##MARKED_BEGIN######################  
    SELECT trnsf_id#,trnsf_recidue_amnt 
    into t_trnsf_id#,t_trnsf_recidue_amnt 
    from d_transfers 
    WHERE trnsf_bacc_amnt > 0
    AND trnsf_recidue_amnt > 0
    AND trnsf_trnsp_id = s_trnsf_trnsp_id
    AND trnsf_bacc_id = s_trnsf_bacc_id
    AND trnsf_cus_id = s_trnsf_cus_id 
    ORDER BY trnsf_transfer_ts ASC limit 1;
    ##MARKED_END######################  


    END LOOP read_loop;

        CLOSE member_cursor;

    SELECT c1;

    END
```

It returns:

```
+-------+
| c1    |
+-------+
| 138 |
+-------+
```

But if I replace the code between MARKED_BEGIN and MARKED_END with code:

```
SET t_trnsf_id = (
SELECT trnsf_id#,trnsf_recidue_amnt 
FROM d_transfers 
WHERE trnsf_bacc_amnt > 0
AND trnsf_recidue_amnt > 0
AND trnsf_trnsp_id = s_trnsf_trnsp_id
AND trnsf_bacc_id = s_trnsf_bacc_id
AND trnsf_cus_id = s_trnsf_cus_id 
ORDER BY trnsf_transfer_ts ASC limit 1 
);
```

I get:

```
+-------+
| c1    |
+-------+
| 54742 |
+-------+
```

I think it should return same results!

If I exclude

```
AND trnsf_trnsp_id = s_trnsf_trnsp_id
AND trnsf_bacc_id = s_trnsf_bacc_id
AND trnsf_cus_id = s_trnsf_cus_id
```

from the code above it returns correct iterations (number of rows in select statement)

I'm using MariaDB 10.1.10 on MacOS

Comment: The continue handler will get called (and thus will end your loop) too if your current `into`-query returns zero results, but not if you replace that part with `set t_trnsf_id = `, which does not have `into`. You may want to add an additional check for that, e.g. if your value cannot be null, try `if t_trnsf_id is null then leave ...`.

Answer (score 0):

@Solarflare, thank you for the hint! Adding CONTINUE HANDLER resolves the problem.

```
BEGIN
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = FALSE;
  BEGIN
    -- body of handler

    ##MARKED_BEGIN######################  
    SELECT trnsf_id,trnsf_recidue_amnt 
    into t_trnsf_id,t_trnsf_recidue_amnt 
    from d_transfers 
    WHERE trnsf_bacc_amnt > 0
    AND trnsf_recidue_amnt > 0
    AND trnsf_trnsp_id = s_trnsf_trnsp_id
    AND trnsf_bacc_id = s_trnsf_bacc_id
    AND trnsf_cus_id = s_trnsf_cus_id 
    ORDER BY trnsf_transfer_ts ASC limit 1;
    ##MARKED_END######################  

  END;
END;
```